# Interactive commands for FTP

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Can someone explain me what does each command mean specifically.
Like what does   `ftp -n`   mean or  `ftp -g` mean.

```
FTP [-v] [-d] [-i] [-n] [-g] [-s:filename] [-a] [-A] [-x:sendbuffer] [-r:recvbuf fer] [-b:asyncbuffers] [-w:windowsize] [host]
```

Comment: Have you already tried to type `ftp -?` in the command prompt window??

Comment: What about `ftp /?` ?

Comment: `-n            No auto-login.`

Comment: Thank you @Dominique , it clearly explains all the commands

Comment: Thank you @aschipfl for clarifying the doubt   :-)